# Problemas de conexión php con un servicio de hosting

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, hosting

Hace poco compré un servicio de *host* (**hostinguer**) y realizo pruebas de conexión con **php**. En **XAMMP** no me marca ningún error, sin embargo cuando conecto mi **php** al servicio de *host*, no se almacena en la base de datos del servidor.

Mi plan de *host* cubre a la perfección una simple conexión **php** mediante un formulario. En **XAMMP** funciona a la perfección.

¿A que se debe ?

Mi dominio: tostadafrancesa.online

---

```
<?php
     include("conexion.php");

     if(isset($_POST['registro']))
     {
     $nombre = trim($_POST['nombre']);
     $email = trim($_POST['email']);
     $horario = trim($_POST['horario']);
     $nivel = trim($_POST['nivelSeleccionado']);
     $fecha = date('y/m/d');

    // Validar el campo "nombre"
 if (strlen($nombre) < 1 || strlen($nombre) > 20 || !preg_match('/^[\p{L}\s]+$/u', $nombre)) {
    ?>
    <p class="error">El campo 'Prénom' debe contener solo letras, espacios y acentos, y no superar los 20 caracteres.</p>
    <?php
    return;
}

    // Validar el campo "email"
    if (strlen($email) < 1 || !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        ?>
        <p class="error">Ingrese un correo electrónico válido</p>
        <?php
        return;
    }
    
    // Verificar si el correo electrónico ya existe en la base de datos
    $consultaEmail = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM inscripciones WHERE email = '$email'";
    $resultadoEmail = mysqli_query($conex, $consultaEmail);
    
    if ($resultadoEmail) {
        $fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultadoEmail);
        $total = $fila['total'];
    
        if ($total > 0) {
            ?>
            <p class="error">El correo electrónico ya está registrado</p>
            <?php
            return;
        }
    } else {
        ?>
        <p class="error">Error al verificar el correo electrónico</p>
        <?php
        return;
    }

    // Validar el campo "horario"
    if (strlen($horario) < 1 || !preg_match('/^(1[1-9]|20):(00|30)$/', $horario)) {
        ?>
        <p class="error">El campo 'Horaire' debe tener un formato válido (HH:00 o HH:30) y estar dentro del rango de 11:00 a 20:30</p>
        <?php
        return;
    }

    // Validar el campo "nivelSeleccionado"
    if (strlen($nivel) < 1 || !preg_match('/^(a1|A1|b1|B1|a2|A2|b2|B2)$/', $nivel)) {
        ?>
        <p class="error">El campo 'Niveau du Francais' solo puede contener los valores 'a1', 'A1', 'a2', 'A2', 'b1', 'B1', 'b2' o 'B2'</p>
        <?php
        return;
    }

    // Realizar la inserción en la base de datos
    $consulta = "INSERT INTO inscripciones(nombre, email, horario, nivel, fecha)
                 VALUES ('$nombre', '$email', '$horario', '$nivel', '$fecha')";

    $resultado = mysqli_query($conex, $consulta);

    if ($resultado) {
        ?>
        <p class="success">Tu inscripción ha sido completada, en un total de 24 horas nos comunicaremos contigo! A bientot!</p>
        <?php
    } else {
        ?>
        <p class="error">Intenta de nuevo, su registro no ha sido completado correctamente</p>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Mi conexión funciona bien, quiero decir, se almacenan los datos, hice pruebas `echo` de conexión y conecta con la bd phpmyadmin del host. Este es mi archivo que registra los datos.

Comment: Podrían ser diferentes cosas, para empezar que no se esté realizando bien la conexión de la DDBB con el cliente en PHP, ya sea por poner mal las credenciales, host o cualquier cosa. También puede ser que no tengas activo el servicio. No se podrían ser bastantes cosas y se queda muy abierta la pregunta...

Comment: Como dice el compañero, la pregunta deja muchas dudas:

1) ¿La base de datos se subió bien al servidor?
2) ¿Las credenciales están correctas? (es habitual que en local tengamos root y password vacío y en producción sea esos datos distintos)
3) En la cadena de conexión ¿pasas el nombre correctamente? (ídem, es habitual que en local tengamos un nombre de bd pero que en servidores dedicados le metan un prefijo) 

Añade algo mas de información, por favor

Comment: Puedes poner el código exacto del servidor? Sin poner el pass de la DB.

Comment: A simple vista no veo nada raro, pueda que en la conexión haya algo. Pon el archivo de conexión sin el Pass (host y base si, porque esos nombres son raros).

Comment: Si era la conexión, tenía mal puesto el nombre del servidor, y por eso no transfería nada a mi bd, gracias